# Calculations based on criteria of other variables using loops and plyr

Tags: r, for-loop, plyr

Here is a simplified example of what I want to do. I have 2 species (Sp) from 2 locations (Loc) and 2 variables (v1 and v2).

```
Loc<-c("L1","L2","L1","L2","L1","L2","L1","L2")
Sp<-c("Sp1","Sp1","Sp1","Sp1","Sp2","Sp2","Sp2","Sp2")
v1<-c(3.1, 3.8, 4.1, 4.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6)
v2<-c(14,15,16,17,6,7,8,9)
DF<-data.frame(Loc, Sp, v1, v2)
```

I want to pick a random value from v1 from species 1 (Sp1) and divide with all values (v1) of species 2 (Sp2) that meet a certain criteria based on variable 2 (v2). So for instance, I pick a "random" value of v1 of Sp1: 3.1.
I want to divide it with v1 of Sp2 only if the difference in v2 between Sp1 and Sp2 is >=3. In this case, 3.1 could be divided by any value because the difference between 14 and any other value is greater than 3. 
This is what I came up with:

```
Ratio<-numeric(length(v1))
for (i in 1:length(v1)) {
    X1<-sample(DF[which(Sp=="Sp1"),],1, replace=F)
    X2<-sample(DF[which(Sp=="Sp2"),],1, replace=F)
    if(X1$v2-X2$v2>=3) {
      Ratio[i] <- X1$v1/X2$v1
      } else {
      next
        }
}
Ratio
```

Now I want to do that, but for each site separately. In other words, ratios should only be calculated if the two species are at the same location. I believe that ddply could be used for that purpose. However, I cannot get the ddply function to work properly and to calculate ratios for each Location. It gives an empty dataframe of 0 obs and 0 variables.

```
RatioByLoc<-ddply(DF, .(Loc), function(x) {
for (i in 1:length(v1)) {
  X1<-sample(DF[which(x$Sp=="Sp1"),],1, replace=F)
  X2<-sample(DF[which(x$Sp=="Sp2"),],1, replace=F)
  if(X1$v2-X2$v2>=3) {
    Ratio[i] <- X1$v1/X2$v1
  } else {
    next
  }
}
})
RatioByLoc
```

Thank you for your help!
Raph

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please let me know if this solves your problem. I have tweaked the function definition little bit.

```
RatioByLoc<-function(x) {
    Ratio=numeric(length(x$v1))
    for (i in 1:length(x$v1)) {
        X1<-sample(which(x$Sp=="Sp1"),1, replace=F)
        X2<-sample(which(x$Sp=="Sp2"),1, replace=F)
        if(x$v2[X1]-x$v2[X2]>=3) {
            Ratio[i] <- x$v1[X1]/x$v1[X2]
        } else {
            next
        }
    }
    Ratio
}

ddply(.data = DF,.variables = "Loc",.fun = RatioByLoc)
```

Comment: Hi @TUSHAr, thank you very much for your answer, it is really helpful! One problem: when conditions are not met (i.e., diff <3), it gives a value of 0 in the dataframe. I would prefer it to skip it (or give a NA) instead because 0's will affect my means and SD. I thought that the "next" command would do that, but apparently not... I modified the ddply into a dlply so I can work with lists independently for each Loc. Then I removed the 0's: 
`RR<-dlply(.data = DF,.variables = "Loc",.fun = RatioByLoc)
RR$L2<-RR$L2[which(RR$L2>0)]`

Comment: My edit is not very elegant and efficient, so I welcome a better way to do it.

Comment: @RaphLavoie Are you sure that `next` is generating 0? I am not sure about it. In that case you can replace `next` with `Ratio[i]<-NA`. If you can provide data where you got 0, I can check.

Comment: Hi @TUSHAr, if the above v2 vector is replaced by the following: `v2<-c(14,15,16,17,6,7,8,15)`, the code will generate 0s when 15 is selected. Your fix of replacing next with `Ratio[i]<-NA` fixes the issue and gives NAs instead of 0s. Thanks again!